# Suppressing "variable set but not used" warnings in the disabled case of a debug printf macro

Tags: c

There are a ton of questions about suppressing "variable set but not used" warnings, but I haven't found one that addresses my very specific problem, which is a debugging macro defined as follows:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
# define dbg_printf(...) ((void)printf(__VA_ARGS__))
#else
# define dbg_printf(...) ((void)( /* ??? */ ))
#endif
```

A variable that is set unconditionally, and then used only as one of the arguments to dbg_printf, should not trigger "variable set but not used" warnings, whether or not DEBUG is defined.  It should *not* be necessary to annotate such variables at the point of definition. For example, this should be warning-free:

```
struct Thing { int value; struct Thing *next; };
struct Thing *find_first_match(int n, struct Thing *list)
{
    struct Thing *p;
    int searched = 0;
    for (p = list; p; p = p->next) {
        searched++;
        if (p->value == n) break;
    }
    dbg_printf("%s: %s after scanning %d entries\n",
               __func__, p ? "found" : "not found", searched);
    return p;
}
```

I have tried a couple things in place of the `/* ??? */`, but nothing I have tried so far has worked without undesirable side effects:

1. `# define dbg_printf(...) ((void)(0 && (__VA_ARGS__)))`

   Causes some versions of clang to complain about unused *values*, e.g.

   > ```
   > void foo(void) {
   >   dbg_printf("%d\n", 23);
   > }
   > ```
   >
   > ⟶
   >
   > ```
   > test.c:4:14: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
   >   dbg_printf("%d\n", 23);
   >              ^~~~~~
   > ```
2. `# define dbg_printf(...) ((void)(sizeof(__VA_ARGS__)))`

   Causes some versions of clang to complain about misuse of `sizeof`, e.g. same test case

   > ```
   > test.c:4:14: warning: sizeof on pointer operation will return size of 'const char *'
   >                       instead of 'const char [4]' [-Wsizeof-array-decay]
   >   dbg_printf("%d\n", 23);
   >              ^~~~~~
   > ```
3. [Edited to add:] An inline variadic function that does nothing, instead of a macro, e.g.

   > ```
   > static inline void dbg_printf(const char *msg, ...) {
   >   (void)msg;
   > }
   > ```

   is no good because its arguments will still be evaluated for their
   side effects, and the offending code base has lots of instances of
   stuff like

   > ```
   >   // code that mutates a global data structure, and then ...
   >   dbg_printf("validation status after %s: %s\n", __func__,
   >              expensive_global_data_structure_validation());
   > ```

Please suggest a construct that can be used in place of the `/* ??? */` that will suppress "variable set but not used" warnings *without* introducing other spurious diagnostics in their place. If this can be done with strictly conforming C2011 code, that is preferable.  Compiler extensions are acceptable *if and only if* they work correctly on all four of:

- gcc 4.8
- gcc 9.x
- clang 7.0
- clang 10.0

Yes, we are stuck using old compilers for good reasons, or at least reasons which nobody has the spare cycles to overcome.

Comment: Have you tried declaring and defining a variadic function, getting the va_list for the parameters, but nothing else (checking that the function calls are optimized away, of course)?

Comment: The "right" solution — which is a huge nuisance, and has several other potential problems — is to laboriously put `#ifdef DEBUG` around the `int searched = 0;` line and the `searched++;` line and everywhere else `searched` is maintained.  (I'm *not* recommending this, because it's something I've contemplated but rejected several times I've had this exact problem.  It's a good question, and I don't have a good answer.)

Comment: You could use a static inline function `static inline int dummy_printf(const char *restrict fmt, ...) { return 0; }`. Then `#define dbg_printf(...) ((void)dummy_printf(__VA_ARGS__))`. You may need to turn on optimization to really obey the `inline` keyword, or use some non-standard forced-inline keyword.

Comment: @PhilMasteG I used your suggestion in my comment above, but I see no need to use a `va_list` if the parameters are not being used.

Comment: My `dummy_printf` function definition might result in an "unused argument" warning on some compilers. Using the argument in a void expression statement such as `(void)fmt;` seems to convince most of those compilers to suppress the warning.

Comment: Does `#define dbg_printf(...) ((void)(__VA_ARGS__))` not work?

Comment: @EricPostpischil It doesn't get rid of the `-Wunused-value` warnings.

Comment: A function that does nothing would still have its parameters evaluated for their side effects, and we have a bunch of cases of `dbg_printf("expensive check: %s\n", expensive_check());`  I'll add that to the question.

Comment: If that's what you want, but it can lead to heisenbugs if you are not careful, similar to using `assert`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, that is an intentional design decision made in full awareness of the consequences.

Answer (score 3):

I use this trick to disable such warnings:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
# define dbg_printf(...) ((void)printf(__VA_ARGS__))
#else
# define dbg_printf(...) do { if ((0)) (void)printf(__VA_ARGS__); } while (0)
#endif
```

This macro generates no code in optimized builds but does not complain about variables initialized and only used inside the argument list.

I use `do { ... } while (0)` to encapsulate the `if` statement in a block so the macro can be used as a regular function call in a context where a single statement is needed such as this:

```
    if (something_went_wrong())
        dbg_printf("something went wrong\n");
    else
        keep_going();
```

I write the test `if ((0))` with a double pair or parentheses to avoid a warning on constant expression always false and/or unreachable code. **clang** would issue a warning about unreachable code with `-Weverything` (which includes `-Wunreachable-code`). They recommend the use of redundant parentheses to silence this warning in contexts where it is the programmer's intent.

`do { } while (0)` does not trigger this warning because it is a classic idiom to group statements as a single statement.

The `{}` are redundant to, the macro could be simplified as:

```
#define dbg_printf(...) do if((0))(void)printf(__VA_ARGS__);while(0)
```

The same goal can be reached with a simpler logical expression, that may or may not trigger other compiler warnings:

```
#define dbg_printf(...) ((void)(((0)) && printf(__VA_ARGS__)))
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the double parentheses in `if ((0))`? (And not in `while (0)` :-?)

Comment: It doesn't really need the braces.

Comment: @rici: `if ((0))` to avoid a warning on constant expression always false on some compilers. `do { } while (0)` does not trigger this warning because it is a classic idiom to group statements as a single statement. I use the `do {} while(0)` wrapper here to allow `if (something) dbg_printf(xxx); else something_else();`

Comment: @IanAbbott: correct, none of `{}`, spaces,`(void)` are needed.

Comment: Here is a simpler alternative: `((void)(((0)) && printf(__VA_ARGS__)))`

Comment: @rici: I am aware of that :) but your comment made me realise that the warning about constant test expressions is not produced for `do {} while (0)`... And other readers might wonder why I used this construction

Comment: I've never encountered the use of the extra set of parentheses to avoid a warning on testing constant expression before. Is that a commonly supported suppression technique for those compilers that moan about such things (I'm guessing MSVC, mostly)?

Comment: Oh, that's clever, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @IanAbbott: `clang` would issue a warning about unreachable code with `-Weverything` which includes `-Wunreachable-code` unless I use `if ((0))...`

Comment: I guess that falls into the class of "compiler quirks that are useful to know". Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. What I was going to write: It seems to me extraordinary that `-Weverything` (which I think should be written `-Wbe-my-hypercritical-uncle-Mort`) focusses on the pettifogging critique of `if (0)`, and apparently ignores what OP wants ignored, which is `if (0) printf("%d", ++count);`. (My uncle Mort would have done the same, I suspect.) IMHO, suppressing the increment of the variable once you switch from debug to production builds is *much* more likely to create bizarre production-only bugs. But whatever....

Comment: What I observed while drafting the above: I tried your construct but with just a regular `(0)` on all odd versions of clang from 5 to 13, which is what I happen to have installed. None of them triggered the unreachable code warning. My hypothesis is that Clang suppresses the warning if the `if(0)` is in a macro.

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
# define dbg_printf(...) ((void)printf(__VA_ARGS__))
#else
# define dbg_printf(...) ((void)(0 && printf(__VA_ARGS__)))
#endif
```

As the right-hand side of the `&&` operator won't be evaluated.

Alternately:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
# undef DEBUG
# define DEBUG 1
#else
# define DEBUG 0
#endif
```

Then:

```
#define dbg_printf(...) ((void)(DEBUG && printf(__VA_ARGS__)))
```

That way you have if multiple such definitions depending on `DEBUG` you only need a single `#ifdef`.

Comment: Rather than redefining `DEBUG`, how about using `defined(DEBUG) &&`?

Comment: @IanAbbott Doesn't compile.  `defined` can only be used in an `#if` condition.

Comment: Yes, I realized my mistake. I just don't like the redefining part. Maybe `#undef DEBUG_` `#ifdef DEBUG` `#define DEBUG_ 1` `#else` `#define DEBUG_ 0` `#endif`. Then use `(DEBUG_ &&`. (Assuming `DEBUG_` can be reserved for this usage.)